# Count object with maxnr in category with DAX

Tags: count, max, powerbi, categories, dax

I am building a report in Power BI for all the calls we do.
Down below is a simplified version of the data I work with (we produce 1250 calls per hour, so my data is a lot bigger than this).

Every row is a call attempt, the first column defines who the attempt was to, the second in which week, the third the attemptnr and the last column states the status of the phone call. 
For example: We called ID 1 two times, the first time in week 1 which ended in status 310 (means callback) and the second time in week 2 which ended in status 710 (positive conversion).

The problem: I want to make a count of all the people (Call ID's) who are still waiting on a phone call (last call status = 310). 
If I use: `CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(data[ID]), data[Status] = 310)` the `result = 3`. Which makes sense: PBI counts 3 times a 310 status.

But it should count only 1, because ID 1 & 2 are already called back and have a positive result (710 & 711). So it needs to look to the highest `attemptnr`.
So I tried: `CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Blad1[ID]), FILTER(Blad1,MAX(Blad1[Attempt])), Blad1[Status] = 310)` But this also results in a count of 3.

I've found solutions in which you make a calculated column, but I also want to combine this with a slicer on the `weeknumber`, so I can check what the callbacks in a specified week are.

So basically I need PBI to count the ID's with a certain status (310) with max attempt. Does anybody know how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Sometimes, a picture is worth a thousand words and in this case it would really help to understand what you are asking. Can you post a picture of your table(s) and/or your model?